# Как в jQuery отобрать только те siblings, что идут до текущего элемента?

Tags: jquery

Т.е., например:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    // как здесь получить все sibling li, что находятся выше текущего li?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).